# haskell power function

Tags: function, haskell, overloading

how to write a power function which makes use of the following facts: To raise x to a power n (where n is a positive whole number), if n  is even, you can find the nth power of x by squaring half that power. For example, x^12 is x^6 * x^6. For odd powers, just subtract one from the power, and multiply the result for the smaller power by x. for example, x^13  is x * x^12, which is x * x^6 * x^6. Recursively, any power can be found with less work than multiplying x by itself the number of times indicated.
I came up with this

```
power x n
    | n == 0  =  1
    | x == 0  =  0
    | even n = ( power x (n / 2) ) * ( power x (n / 2) )
    | odd n = x * ( power x ((n - 1) / 2)) * ( power x ((n - 1) / 2) )
```

but I get an error saying ERROR - Unresolved overloading
*** Type       : (Integral a, Fractional a) => Integer
*** Expression : power 2 2

Comment: Looks like you're using Hugs. You might want to upgrade to GHC and [The Haskell Platform](http://haskell.org/platform) for a better Haskell experience.

Comment: @Don it's likely that this is for a class, in which case Hugs may be mandatory.

Comment: just started haskell last week I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: hmm , is just like 5^10 =25^5. so the even part u need to power(x*x, n/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a remark now that your code is running: Haskell doesn't automatically memoize functions, so you're calculating the recursive calls to `power` twice in the last two lines. I would recommend to introduce a simple function `sqr k = k * k` and to use it. There are several ways: a separate function; a `where` clause; and `let`.

I would prefer `let`:

```
power _ 0 = 1
power 0 _ = 0
power x n  = let sqr k = k * k
                 half_n = n `div` 2  
                 sqrHalfPower = sqr ( power x half_n )
             in if even n then sqrHalfPower else x * sqrHalfPower
```

As you can see pattern matching deals with the first two cases. Then `let` defines some useful expressions, which can be used later in `in`. Note that for odd numbers, `` (n-1) `div` 2 `` gives the same result as `` n `div` 2 ``, so we can unify both cases.

Answer (score 4):

What's happened here is a common type mismatch. First, take a look at the type signature for `even`: `even :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool`. `odd` has a similar signature. So you can see that `even` and `odd` take any type of the `Integral` typeclass and evaluate it. Then look at the signature for `/`: `(/) :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a`. `/` takes only `Fractional` types, not `Integral` ones. It's impossible for one type to be evaluated by both those functions. In this case, there's an easy fix: use `div` instead of `/`. Note that if you use `div` as an infix function (place it between the arguments) you'll need to put backticks around `div`.

Comment: I did this
'| even n = ( power x (n (div) 2) ) * ( power x (n (div) 2) )'
ERROR file:.\assign11.hs:2 - Type error in function binding
*** Term           : power
*** Type           : a -> ((c -> c -> c) -> d -> b) -> a
*** Does not match : a -> b -> a
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type

Comment: @biz I don't know much about Hugs error messages, but I believe that means the type signature of the function and the type it's actually returning don't match. Did you forget the backticks, perhaps? For example the fourth line of your program should like this: `| even n = ( power x (n 'div' 2) ) * ( power x (n 'div' 2) )`. Do NOT copy and paste that code, because I used apostrophes instead of backticks because of stackoverflow's markup syntax. Every apostrophe in that line should be replaced with a backtick (`), which is probably above the tab key on your keyboard.

Comment: @biz Great! If you ever get a problem like this again, you can look up the type signature of a function using [hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/), or using GHCI if you ever get GHC and [The Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/), which is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the type of `even` and compare that to the type of `/`.

Comment: even is boolean if it retrns True then the function returns what I defined on it I'm not sure I got what u mean by comparing those

Comment: @biz The type of a function includes the types of its arguments, not just the type it returns. What are the types of their arguments?

Comment: ohh ok n is a positive integer

Answer (score 1):

I think, the fastest way to calculate power:

```
     pow:: Integer->Integer->Integer
     pow x n  |(n==1) = x
              |even n = (pow x ( div n 2))*(pow x ( div n 2)) 
              |odd n  = x * (pow x (n-1))
```

you can also use "Int" instead "Integer"(replace Integer  on Int in the signature!).

Comment: Don't forget to add `|(n==0)=1` guard case! Without it for me at least this implementation didn't compile.